# Sequelize Default Exclude

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a table named `person`, I want a column to be excluded as default,

```
const Person = sequelize.define('person',{
  secretColumn: Sequelize.STRING,
  //... and other columns
});
```

I see that there is a feature called `Scope` in Sequelize:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html

I tried to exclude like this;

```
const Person = sequelize.define('person',{
  secretColumn: Sequelize.STRING,
  //... and other columns
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    exclude: ['secretColumn']
  }
});
```

But that does't work. Is there any other way to exclude a column by default?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I firgured it out. `exclude` needs to be in `attributes` part:

```
const Person = sequelize.define('person',{
  secretColumn: Sequelize.STRING,
  //... and other columns
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: { exclude: ['secretColumn'] }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this isn't working for me. Is it okay to do this? defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['token', 'access', 'password'] }
  }